# Handling page submission and data validation in Selenium

Tags: selenium

Once I fill one web page (let's call it FirstPage) with correct data and submit it I will get SecondPage. But if I enter wrong data and click submit there will be error messages written on FirstPage, and SecondPage will not appear. In my tests I am testing "happy paths" and then I need FirstForm to be submitted, but I also have negative tests including data validation with wrong data and then I need to catch all the error messages reported on FirstPage.
I have used this approach of handling this and I am interested to hear if you agree or disagree and have better ways.

```
public class FirstPage {

    public SecondPage clickSubmit() {
        webDriver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);

        try {   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("someElementOnSecondPage")));
        return new SecondPage();
        } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
            return null;
        }
}

    public List<String> getAllErrorMessages() throws Exception {
        // code for getting all error messages
    }

}


public class FirstPageTest {

    @Test
    public void dataValidation() throws Exception {
        // some intial code where I create firstPage and fill it with BAD data

        firstPage.submit();
        List<String> allMessages = firstPage.getAllErrorMessages();

        // Check if messages are fine or not

    }

}
```

In the tests where I want to properly submit the page I will not check whether submit() method returned SecondPage or null. I will just continue the test as SecondPage was returned and if it wasn't the test will fail. I think I will never need to check what is returning value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of references on the web for things like this. [This one](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) comes to mind.

This really should look more like the below

Locators like this would be at the top of the class

```
private By submitButtonLocator = By.id("submit");
```

and this would be a method of the class

```
public SecondPage clickSubmit()
{
    webDriver.findElement(submitButtonLocator).click();
    return new SecondPage();
}
```

You should have checks in your page object constructor that determines if you're on the right page. That validation will fail if you aren't on the second page as you expect. You don't need to validate in the method. That validation actually breaks one of the page object model rules which is that locators should only exist with the page object that they are found, e.g. `By.name("someElementOnSecondPage")` should only exist within the `SecondPage` class. If that locator ever changed and it existed in more than just `SecondPage`, you'd have to go find all the references... which is not a good thing.

Comment: Thanks man, you made a few valid points here. I'm mostly surprised with how badly I was using locators.